# No java in $PATH

Tags: java, linux, path

I installed a Linux virtual machine, and downloaded JDK on it. Then I did:

```
$ export PATH=~/jdk1.8.0_191/bin:$PATH
```

Then

```
$ which java
```

And it said that I have no `java` in `PATH`. I checked the `bin` file in my JDK and there is a file named `java` in there. What do I do? My operating system is CentOS 6 64-bit, and I downloaded the JDK for Linux x64.

I also tried the `export` without the `:$PATH`, and then `which java`, and it still says there is no `java` in there.

Comment: What do you get when you run `~/jdk1.8.0_191/bin/java -version`?

Comment: Try replacing ~ with the full path

Comment: Also, if the file is called JAVA, If won't work. Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: i will suggest add `JAVA_HOME` and then add it to `PATH`

Comment: I got it! The problem is actually that I followed an online tutorial, and the ~/ led me to the wrong directory. Everything worked fine after that. Still thanks!

Comment: @MaggieMao Could you please unselect my answer? It's totally wrong

Comment: @Mad Physicist Okay I unselected it